# Windows 10 randomly freezing after upgrade to AMD FX-8350 CPU

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, cpu, freeze

Windows 10 is randomly freezing after upgrading to an AMD FX-8350. The previous CPU was a quad core AMD FX 4300.
There were no freezing issues with the previous CPU at all.

The PC specs are:

- Motherboard: Gygabyte 970A-DS3P southbridge rev. 40
- Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8350 4.2 Ghz Eight-Core Processor
- Video Card: nvidia GeForce GTX 970 (Latest drivers via geforce experience)
- RAM: 16 GB 2000Mhz DDR3
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10 (build 17134), 64-bit
  (reactivated and updated since hardware change)
- Power Supply: Corsair 700w

Installed all the latest driver software for all components.

My poor gaming rig is pretty useless at the moment, so any answers are appreciated.

Update.
I have the latest BIOS version, according to Gygabyte.
Latest is the FD release, and it is installed.
I'd heard that people had issues with certain CPU's on older versions.
My CPU is definitely in the supported CPU's list for this board.

[image: BIOS image]

Comment: First guess is a driver issue

Comment: That was the first thing i tried, from all component vendors.

Comment: have you completely uninstalled the old CPU drivers?

Comment: I mean, are you sure you're not using MS drivers but the vendor drivers. Did you try to load into safe mode?

Comment: Performed a full re-install and drive format before it was even powered on with the new cpu in

Comment: anything noteworthy happening before or during freezes? Too much RAM usage? 100% drive usage? random apps starting? etc.

Comment: what says eventvwr.msc?

Comment: It's been inconsistent with event viewer. First it happened the same time as a USB wi fi card so i ditched it for LAN, then it happened the same time as an error for an apple app ID, so uninstalled all apple software etc. Just impossible to pin down it seems. I eventually added a clean install to that ^.

Comment: try to monitor the task manager and rang process with CPU occupancy volume when computer freeze. Try to uninstall the existing CPU driver and reboot comptuer to load a general driver to check.